# Elasticsearch and Angular 2

Tags: angular, elasticsearch

I'm using Angular 2 with `angular-cli` and I installed the elasticsearch library with

```
nom install --save elasticsearch
```

There is an `elasticsearch` directory in `node_modules`.

I do the import with

```
import * as elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch';
```

As I understand this is a relative path that will resolve to the `node_modules` path and `angular-cli` (with `ng serve`) will take care of bundling everything properly.

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/xxx/yyy/src/app/shared/elasticsearch/es.service.ts:4:31 
Cannot find module 'elasticsearch'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I confirmed that the problem appears with an empty project generated with `ng init`.

Also, doing something like this:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
```

works well.

Comment: @LauraAbadAvilés Is this an answer to my question or another question?

Comment: It was a question, but I figure it out. client = new elasticsearch.Client({
            host: 'http://localhost:9200',
            //log: 'trace'
        });

Comment: @LauraAbadAvilés Yes indeed. What about my question and Angular2, how did you import the library?

Comment: I imported same as you: ngOnInit(){
        this.es = require('elasticsearch')
    }

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Never fully understood how to do it better than with the 'require', but I didn't investigate since then.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get this working, is to first install the type definitions:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/elasticsearch
```

And then, armed with your new shiny types, you can use import statements like this one:

```
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';
```

... and use it like this:

```
let x = new Client({ /* Your parameters here */});
```